# Help with Rigging Poncho-Style Cloth

Tags: modeling, rigging, unity

I've recently found this piece of artwork by Janice Chu (https://www.artstation.com/klangoda):
[image]

The character is wearing a kind of poncho that's draped over both shoulders. Now, the rig I'm making is going into Unity, so the blender cloth simulation is out of the question, because the character in the game is going to have changeable clothes. So I tried to go with the standart rigging method of "Automatic Weights", and this came out:

[image]

So far so good, but then when I move the arms this happens (Green = Where is should be, Red = Where it is now):

[image]

Would you guys have any tips or ideas on how I might make this work?
If nothing works I guess I can always go back to Unity's cloth system but that's expensive in both performance and workload.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from your second picture that anything went wrong. And you don't explicitly tell us what the problem is. Consider doing so, since the picture isn't sufficing to make the problem clear.

Comment: I changed the image to make it more clear, thank you!

Comment: What happens when you try to weight paint? Does it make any difference to this outcome?